# Create CLLocation using WhirlyGlobe

Tags: ios, cllocation

I have attempted creating a cllocation object using the tapmessage's wheregeo and worldloc properties. however the lat and lon & x, y values that i get from them are not able to be used to create a cllocation object. Maybe i am formatting incorrectly?

Thanks in advances

logging this

```
GeoCoord coord = msg.whereGeo;
Point3f point = msg.worldLoc;
NSLog(@"x point is %f",point.x());
NSLog(@"y point is %f",point.y());
NSLog(@"from wheregeo %f",coord.lat());
NSLog(@"from wheregeo %f",coord.lon());
```

gives me this

2012-01-19 12:30:22.491 WhirlyGlobeApp[1068:4007] x point is -0.138646

2012-01-19 12:30:22.492 WhirlyGlobeApp[1068:4007] y point is 0.554229

2012-01-19 12:30:22.493 WhirlyGlobeApp[1068:4007] from wheregeo 0.962698

2012-01-19 12:30:22.494 WhirlyGlobeApp[1068:4007] from wheregeo 1.815925

I am using the cllocation default init with latittude and longitude method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be radians vs. degrees.  The coordinates are in radians, but you probably need degrees for `CLLocation`.

Just use the `RadToDeg()` template in `GlobeMath.h`.  It looks weird, but just call it like a function.